# Strange grep behaviour in scripts

Tags: linux, bash, grep

In one of my tools is needed the PID of specyfic process in system. I try do this by following command:

```
parasit@host:~/# ps -ef | grep beam.smp |grep -v grep |awk '{ print $2 }' |head -n1
11982
```

Works fine, but when i try use the same command in script in the vast majority of cases got PID of **grep** instead of target process (beam.smp in this case) despite of 'grep -v grep`.

```
parasit@host:~/# cat getPid.sh
#!/bin/bash

PROC=$1    
#GET PID
CMD="ps -ef | grep $PROC |grep -v grep |awk '{ print \$2 }' |head -n1"
P=`eval $CMD`


parasit@host:~/# bash -x ./getPid.sh beam.smp 
+ PROC=beam.smp
+ CMD='ps -ef |grep beam.smp |grep -v grep |awk '\''{ print $2 }'\'' |head -n1'
++ eval ps -ef '|grep' beam.smp '|grep' -v grep '|awk' ''\''{' print '$2' '}'\''' '|head' -n1
+++ head -n1
+++ awk '{ print $2 }'
+++ grep -v grep
+++ grep beam.smp
+++ ps -ef
+ P=2189
```

Interestingly, it is not deterministic, I know it sounds strange, but sometimes it works OK, and sometimes no, I have no idea what it depends on.

How it is possibile? Is there any better method to get rid of "grep" from results?

BR
Parasit

Comment: Better to use `pgrep` if you have it

Comment: You exclude `grep`, but you don't exclude `getPid`.

Comment: Does it fail for `beam.smp` or other values? How do you know that it is PID of `grep`  process?

Comment: did you try `grep '[b]eam.smp` ? Then you won't need the `grep -v grep`. Good luck.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès first time when i got wrong result i tried same command without "awk | head" and saw 2 results, grep and beam.smp. Grep was first with lower PID.

Comment: @parasit I wasn't able to reproduce your problem on different systems... Could you post the *wrong* result?

Answer (score 1):

`pidof -s` is made for that (`-s`: single ID is returned):

```
pidof -s "beam.smp"
```

However, `pidof` also returns defunct (zombie, dead) processes. So here's a way to get PID of the first alive-and-running process of a specified command:

```
# function in bash

function _get_first_pid() {
  ps -o pid=,comm= -C "$1" | \
     sed -n '/'"$1"' *$/{s:^ *\([0-9]*\).*$:\1:;p;q}'
}

# example

_get_first_pid "beam.smp"
```

---

1. `-o pid=,comm=`: list only PID and COMMAND columns; ie. only list what we need to check; if all are listed then it is more difficult to process later on
2. `-C "$1"`: of the command specified in `-C`; ie. only find the process of that specific command, not everything
3. `sed`: print only PID for first line that do not have "defunct" or anything after the base command name

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.